# Buttons & checkboxes are not keeping track of each other

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function that lets you press a button only if you checked a checkbox, this is what I have written so far, it starts as false so the button gets is disabled, but when i check the checkbox it doesn't work
My code :

```
            var gdprAccepted = false
                if(gdprAccepted == true){
                    $('#btn-wheel-submit').prop("disabled", "false");
                } else {
                    $('#btn-wheel-submit').prop("disabled", "true");
                }
        } 
    });
} 
        function gdprChecker() {
            if($('#gdprCheck').is(':checked')){
                gdprAccepted = true;
                console.log(gdprAccepted);
            } else {
                gdprAccepted = false;
                console.log(gdprAccepted);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making this more complex than it needs to be:

```js
function updateButton(checkbox) {
  checkbox.form.b0.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb0" onclick="updateButton(this)"><br>
  <button name="b0" disabled onclick="console.log('Enabled')">Button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check your checkbox is clicked(enabled). If enable then remove the disabled attribute from button. Like following

```js
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
 var sendbtn = document.getElementById('buttonId');
 // when unchecked or checked, run the function
 checker.onchange = function(){
if(this.checked){
    sendbtn.disabled = false;
} else {
    sendbtn.disabled = true;
}

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
<input type="submit" class="inputButton" disabled="disabled" id="buttonId" value="Button " onclick='alert("enabled")'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#check').click(function(){
if($(this).prop('checked')){
$('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
}else{
$('#btn').prop('disabled', true)
}
})
})
```

```html
<!-- Using Jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
<input type="submit"  disabled="disabled" id="btn" value="Button" onclick='console.log("button is Enabled")' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cbox = document.getElementById('check');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
cbox .addEventListener('click',function(){
if(cbox.checked){
btn.disabled = false;
}else{
btn.disabled = true; 
}
})
```

```html
<!-- Using Javscript-->
<input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
<input type="submit" class="inputButton" disabled="disabled" id="btn" value="Button" onclick='console.log("button is Enabled")' />
```